# FlxNapeSprite and collisions

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, nape

I'm using Nape Physics with the dev version of HaxeFlixel. I have a few FlxNameSprites moving around in my game. Nape's own handling of collision resolution is excellent, but how do I make my own code react to the collisions happening too?

I.e if player 1 and player 2 collide, Nape resolves the collisions and the physics happens. How can I make some of my own code run too? What is the Nape equivalent of FlxG.overlap()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use listeners for tracking:
Create [CbTypes](http://napephys.com/help/manual.html#Callbacks.CbTypes) for objects, than assign them to corresponding bodies.
Than create collision [listener](http://napephys.com/docs/types/nape/callbacks/InteractionListener.html) for that CbTypes and add it to space

```
var CBODY1 = new CbType();
var CBODY2 = new CbType();
player1.body.cbTypes.add(CBODY1);
player2.body.cbTypes.add(CBODY1);

collisionListener = new InteractionListener(
        CbEvent.BEGIN,
        InteractionType.COLLISION,
        CBODY1,
        CBODY2,
        onCollide
    );

space.listeners.add(collisionListener);

private function onCollide(cb:InteractionCallback):Void
{
    trace("COLLIDE");
}
```